# ¿Cómo cambiar un texto al seleccionar un archivo desde un input de tipo file?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, cshtml

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación `MVC .Net` que tiene una parte visual en `cshtml` .
El problema viene en la siguiente parte: Tengo un botón para seleccionar un archivo definido así:

```
<div class="col-sm-4">
   @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Data, new { type = "file", @class = "upload " })
   @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Data,"Upload File...", new { type = "file", @class = "btn btn-primary" })
</div>
```

Está de esta forma para poder darle estilo y que se vea como un botón, se muestra de la siguiente manera:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
El problema es que cuando yo selecciono un archivo no se cambia el valor del texto `Upload File...`
¿Existe algún tipo de evento que se dispare cuando se selecciona un archivo? ¿Cuál es la forma óptima de hacer esto?
Un saludo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El evento `change` se dispara cuando subes un fichero. Por ejemplo con **jquery** podrías hacer así:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input[type='file']").change(function(){
        document.getElementById("label").textContent = document.getElementById('Data').value; 
    });
});
```

Comment: Perfecto, para dejar la respuesta al 100%, el código dentro de la función change ha quedado así:
                document.getElementById("label").textContent = document.getElementById('Data').value;

Comment: Perfecto, lo cambio para el que quiera en un futuro utilizarlo